# jCanvas - Fill Rectangles with image

Tags: javascript, image, repeat, fill, jcanvas

Is there a possibility to fill a rectangle with a picture and not with color in jCanvas?

I would repeat the pic in the rectangle like in css for example:

```
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Comment: I solve it with the pattern function. But the picture in there is moving with the layer (it's draggable). How can i stop this????

Answer (score 0):

To fill a pattern with an image, use the [`createPattern()`](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/patterns/) method built into jCanvas. However, due to the limitations of the HTML5 canvas API, you cannot offset a pattern (so as to move it with a draggable layer).

-Caleb